# How to fix an increment attribute not working when saving to the database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, still learning. I am trying to implement in my rails application a autoincrement numbering system. When I create a project I want the client selected to provide the last number used from its t.integer "last_tracking_number_option1", default: 0 column. the code in user.rb generates the option tracking number and passes it to the project_controller create. the problem im having, which I've been searching for days already, is that the incrementing of the tracking number is not working, and I can't seem to figure out why it is not incrementing.

The code is mostly working,the setting generates a tracking code eg. IDEN23-01, but 01 shoud be 02 when creating a new project with the same client. Any help please?

Here is what I got working so far:

```
`class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
  before_save :set_code
  
  def set_code
    if name.present?
    self.code = name.parameterize.upcase.slice(0, 5)
    end
  end
end`

class User < ApplicationRecord
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
 
   has_many :projects
   has_many :clients
   has_many :rates
   has_one :user_setting
 
   enum role: [:user, :admin]
   after_initialize :set_default_role, if: :new_record?
 
   attribute :last_tracking_number_for_option1, :integer, default: 0

   # Define methods to get and update the last tracking number generated for each option
 
   def last_tracking_number_option1
     self.last_tracking_number_for_option1 || 0
   end
 
   def update_last_tracking_number_option1(number)
     self.update(last_tracking_number_for_option1: number)
   end
 
   
 
   # Define methods to generate tracking numbers for each option
 
   def generate_tracking_number_option1(client_id)
    last_number = last_tracking_number_option1
    year = Date.today.year.to_s.slice(2, 2)
    number = format('%02d', last_number + 1)
    update_last_tracking_number_option1(last_number + 1)
    "#{client_id}#{year}-#{number}"
  end
  
 
end



from my projects_controller: 

def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    @client = Client.find_by(id: params[:project][:client_id])
  
    # Use the generate_tracking_number method based on the selected option
    if @client.nil?
      @project.tracking_number = current_user.generate_tracking_number_option1("", last_tracking_number_option1)
    else
      @project.tracking_number = current_user.generate_tracking_number_option1(@client.set_code)
    end
  
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 saved object from console: 


[#<Project:0x0000000105faf860                                      
  id: 12,                                                          
  name: "mmmmmmm",                                                 
  description: "mmmmmmmm",                                         
  status: "Active",                                                
  project_type: "3D Sculpture",                                    
  client_id: 2,                                                    
  user_id: 2,                                                      
  created_at: Thu, 18 May 2023 14:02:40.006548000 UTC +00:00,      
  updated_at: Thu, 18 May 2023 14:02:40.009469000 UTC +00:00,      
  tracking_number: "IDENT23-01">] Note: here is where the problem is, the 01 is not changing. 

from terminal:   Started POST "/projects" for ::1 at 2023-05-19 08:47:34 -0500
Processing by ProjectsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "project"=>{"client_id"=>"2", "name"=>"deede", "description"=>"sdsads", "status"=>"Active", "project_type"=>"3D Sculpture"}, "commit"=>"Create Project"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:38:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:24:in `update_last_tracking_number_option1'
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:24:in `update_last_tracking_number_option1'
  User Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2023-05-19 13:47:34.307757"], ["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:24:in `update_last_tracking_number_option1'
  Project Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("name", "description", "status", "project_type", "client_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "tracking_number") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "deede"], ["description", "sdsads"], ["status", "Active"], ["project_type", "3D Sculpture"], ["client_id", 2], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2023-05-19 13:47:34.309552"], ["updated_at", "2023-05-19 13:47:34.309552"], ["tracking_number", nil]]
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:24:in `update_last_tracking_number_option1'
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:24:in `update_last_tracking_number_option1'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
  Project Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "projects" SET "updated_at" = $1, "tracking_number" = $2 WHERE "projects"."id" = $3  [["updated_at", "2023-05-19 13:47:34.312597"], ["tracking_number", "IDENT23-01"], ["id", 16]]
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:48:in `block in create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/16
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.2ms | Allocations: 9010)
```

Comment: you need to put `debugger` statements in the code, and when the operation stops at the debugger statement, you can inspect the variables to see what is happening that is different from what you intended.

Comment: Tracking number is a project attribute, I think you will find it cleaner to put the code for creating it in the project class.  Having a project belong to both user and client is also going to lead to confusion --> in project get to the user via the client

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I'll give both a try.

Comment: I followed both of your advise Les and dbugger's and I was able to get to the solution, which was simpler than the code itself. I used byebug and then refactored the code to use only project and client and after a few modifications to the properties, it all worked. Like magic!, thank you both. this scenario reminds me of a book I used to read to my kids when they were little called "Simple pictures are best". thank you again.